# Meaning and influence of the tip at the end of Men In Black 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black-3

I know many things did not make sense in Men In Black 3 but the last scene where griffin is eating pie and notices K did not give a tip and looks up to see a meteor and as soon as K remembers and gives the tip Griffin exclaims "That was a close one" and the meteor crashes with something(Satellite?)

My question being what does the tip giving or not giving mean or imply, or how does it affect the future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tip has nothing to do with the meteor.

Griffin can see future events, whether they happen or not.  Griffin sees 2 future paths, **completely irrelevant to each other**.

On one path, a meteor is on a trajectory to hit Earth.  On that timeline, K does not tip.

On another path, a meteor is on a trajectory to hit a satellite.  On that timeline, K leaves a tip.

Completely separate events, the only "indicator" to Griffin is whether or not K leaves a tip.  Once K comes back and leaves the tip, Griffin knows which timeline they're on.

Answer (score 5):

Griffin has the power to see the future in different outcomes i.e he sees almost all the possible future events which is yet to happen. 
 So in the end scene he saw one of the future event where K does not tip, in that event the meteor hits earth ergo, end of the planet.

> Griffin says,"This is New Favorite Moment in Human History,unless this is the one where K forgot to leave the tip."

I want to stress towards **"unless this is the one"**. But this doesn't happen because K returns back to give tip

> "I almost forgot."

thus negating that event and the meteor hits the satellite thus changing its trajectory and the world is safe and Griffin is relieved and says

> "That was a close one."

Comment: Maybe my question is misleading as to what I am asking.I just meant to ask how the tip giving affects the future(I know that this is speculative)

Comment: As I said it is not a fixed future so that it can be changed. It is one of the many future events griffin saw.

Comment: Meaning a chain of events somehow linked to the tip?

Comment: @IshanTaneja You are asking about the chain of events from Kay leaving to tip to the asteroid hitting the satellite. This answer, although it talks about Griffin's abilities, doesn't explain that link. I'm pretty sure the link isn't explained in the movie, and it's kind of silly that it would make an asteroid hit a satellite instead of wiping out life on earth, but I'm still curious about the answer to your question.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Yeah its somehow speculative I think.And probably I could ignore this also with the many other plotholes in the movie.

Comment: No, there is no chain of events, both are merely *parameters*. One doesn't lead to another, they're independent.